# Data/serial connection over 2.5mm audiojack

Tags: linux, terminal, usb, client, reverse-engineering

I have searched and see that there are questions related to this.  Unfortunately I could not find any that related directly or closely to this, most of them are related to android and starting a new project.

I have a device, lets call it a "Camera."  This camera connects to computers and charges via a 2.5mm audio jack on the device and plugs into USB on the PC.  Now this "audio jack" has nothing to do with audio.  It is solely for data and charging.  Now on the PC you download the camera's app from their website and it communicates with the device.  On the PC, under windows and linux, the device installs, but does not mount a drive for data access or anything.  You can only transfer data via their app.  This is fine, their app works great, but I am looking to automate the process, which they offer no ability to do so.

After sniffing some connections and digging through logs I found that it seems to be a serial connection to the camera.  In the logs and piecing together the sniffed traffic I get this.

```html
DEBUG - Console is ready now 
DEBUG - Writing to CLI:  sys info 
DEBUG - Done writing to CLI:  sys info 
DEBUG - Starting console match 
DEBUG - "buildinfo=root@localhost.localdomain (/mnt/windows-share/src/yugi)"
DEBUG - "buildinfo=root@localhost.localdomain (/media/sf_build/CAMERA/flex/src/yugi)" 
DEBUG - "Camera System Program, Ver: 1, Compiled June 11 1909, 12:42:17." 
DEBUG - "Battery Voltage: 4293 mV" 
DEBUG - "Battery charge level: 50%" 
DEBUG - "Charger status: FAST CHARGE" 
DEBUG - "BT Device Name: CAMERA" 
DEBUG - "BT Device Address: 000000:000000" 
DEBUG - "Hardware Board Revision: 0xE " 
DEBUG - "CL HW Board Revision: 0xE " 
DEBUG - "Hardware BT Stub PsKey:  0x970E " 
DEBUG - "Camera: CAMERA CC9Y129" 
DEBUG - "BT Firmware Revision: 1" 
DEBUG - "Link Key: 00000000000000000000000000000000" 
DEBUG - "GUID: 00000000000000000000000000000000" 
DEBUG - Console is ready now 
DEBUG - Directory path  "0:/DCIM/100VIDEO" 
DEBUG - "0:/DCIM/100VIDEO" 
DEBUG - Scanning successful
```

So this seems to be the app sending commands to the device.  I have been unsuccessful in trying to get a terminal to connect to the device as no serial comms register to the host OS, the camera's driver simply enables to the app to see said camera.  Now digging through the drivers, a .dll called "flex.dll" seems to be the one doing the communication portion.  Opening it up in a text editor (Yes I know, not how its done but I know nothing of reverse engineering) I get things like this.

```html
pattern=QT_PLUGIN_VERIFICATION_DATA
version=4.8.5
debug=true
buildkey=Windows msvc release full-config TFlexGen1::sendBuf partial write    
TFlexGen1::sendBuf  TFlexGen1::recvBuf  orientation taser-cam-flex  build-info 
fw-update   fw-updt-end-signal  file-size   del-video   get-video   
rec-quality video-buffer    mic dev-mode    ann-file    video-list  device-clock   
fw-multi-updt   flex-bt-version flex-boot-version   fw-version  serial-num  ,  
not-found   Could not mount file system Could not mount file system with drive ID == -1
Failed reading status getting sense Failed to read response to inquiry  Error sending inquiry 
Error setting up control transfer   TFlexGen1::initStorageIFace Could not remount file system  
flex-hw-version Read 50K from CLI, something is wrong. fail readCmdStr exit on stop thread  
readCmdStr failed   Done writing to CLI:    Writing to CLI:     reboot  play 62
```

The only other thing I found is files called QTcore, QTNetwork, and other files labled QT but I have been unable to determine if they play a role in the communications or just the app functions itself.  But if I removed the flex.dll the error logs start reporting that the QTplugin is missing.

On a side note I also get hints of something called SREX almost before every cli command sent.  I have also modified IDs and other identifying info from the logs.

Now, my end goal here is to make a linux (or even windows but I figured linux would be the best route) system to auto read the device like the app and automatically copy files from the camera onto the computer system as my camera is plugged in.  Now I have thought about making a program that auto recognizes and clicks through the appropriate app commands for me.  I will be having multiple cameras plugged in and unplugged throughout the day I am not sure how reliable this would be.

My biggest problem is just getting access to the same cli that the app uses.  I've tried serial ports (No new ones appear when the device is plugged in and app running), usb ports, the only thing I could think of is some sort of SSH over USB? I have no clue, and even then I run into the problem of how to get a terminal to even point to something like that.

I am just left scratching my head here, not sure what else to do.

Comment: Did you try the underwater smoke signal device link?

Comment: I'm tempted to try that right about now.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12498/what-protocol-does-a-headphone-jack-use Maybe you find some information there.

Comment: I've read that and tried looking into that, apologies for not noting that.  But it lead to nothing useful.  As I said the connector is not used for anything to do with audio.  I believe the manufacturer chose this connection type for data security.  (IE not everyone is going to have a 2.5mm to USB cable)

Comment: Did you try running Wireshark? You should be able to listen to the communication on the USB bus (in Linux) and be able to, at least, see the USB side of the cable. It's probable that the cable converts the USB signal into something else on the device's end, but it's the USB side you need anyways.